# PC turns on for a split second then turns off

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

My PC recently stopped working. I turned it on one day and heard a pop then it turned off and when I tried to turn it on it wouldn’t.

I assumed it was the PSU so I changed it but then after trying to turn it on again the fans would spin for a split second and the CPU red light would flash then it would all turn off so I thought the CPU shorted so I changed that too.

Tried it again still nothing so changed the motherboard as well but still nothing.

Afterwards I changed the ram sticks and still nothing. When I supply power to the PC and turn it on all it does now is every fan on the case and every fan on the graphics card spins for a split second then nothing happens (cpu fan does not spin either).

I have absolutely no idea what it could be and I’ve basically built a new pc at this point please help

- **CPU**: Intel i5 96000k
- **GPU**: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060
- **Motherboard**: ASUS Prime z390-p Motherboard
- **RAM**: 2x LPX Vengeance 8gb RAM sticks
- **PSU**: 750watts
- **Hard Drive**: 1TB Hard drive
- **SSD**: 4TB 850 EVO SSD

Comment: Are there any beep codes? https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/

Comment: Look for a burnt connection to Screen or PSU connections.

Comment: There are hundreds of parts in a PC. Replacing each randomly may take hundreds of attempts to "fix" it. Take it to a repair shop where they can test what broke.

Comment: Although I "sort of agree" @DrMoishePippik , I don't.  "Hundreds of attempts".. ?? .. I can usually narrow this down in a few boots. How many parts are there to replace anyway?  I am doing the math and I don't end up with a factorial of hundreds.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik not only that, a defective motherboard could also damage other components if they are mindlessly switched out. A 100$ defect could result in a 1000$ defect